# Alligning The Subtotal Title To The Right - New Order E-mail In Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email, code

I am trying to align the subtotal title to the right after I was told to remove the SKU from the new order e-mail, but everything I do in the coding in `(app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml)` is not working for me. The prices shown on the right is aligned just fine, however, the subtotal title is not.

Any help for me with aligning the subtotal title to the right in the new order e-mail along with the prices would be much appreciated. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Here is the code in default.phtml that I have right now:

```
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Item') ?></th>
        <th align="right" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
        <th align="right" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

and here is the screenshot of the mis-aligned subtotal title in the new order e-mail in Magento 1.9:

[image]

As you can see, the subtotal title in the new order e-mail is not aligned to the right with the prices like it should be, leaving a white gap, which I do not like to see, and I do not like my customers to see at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around you can add an empty `td` before `Subtotal` like:

```
<th align="right" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"></th>
```

**Let me know, If work** Or please share full code of below files:

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items\default.phtml
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items.phtml
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Pawan. The following code that you mentioned did work:

    <th align="right" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"></th>

Comment: Welcome @Shahrooz.